# uninitialized constant Formtastic::I18n::SCOPES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 6.0.1, Puma 4.3.0, Devise 4.7.1, ActiveAdmin 2.4.0, Formtastic 3.1.5.

---

Once again I am creating a Rails application. Created the foundation. A couple of models. Made a simple front-end for them. Next install Devise, ActiveAdmin.

In general, nothing unusual. Locally everything works fine.

But on the server, some kind of nonsense began to happen with ActiveAdmin.

In general, the application on the server is working fine. Through the console, I can create all the data. These data are successfully displayed on the site.

But if I go into ActiveAdmin...

Dashboard page displayed successfully. But if I go to the index page of any entity, then I will get the following error (from the log):

```
2019-11-19T00:55:04.216309411Z app[web.1]: web| I, [2019-11-19T00:55:04.198819 #14]  INFO -- : [9ac98910-3a38-496d-9f5e-f276bc590ba7]   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activeadmin-2.4.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb (Duration: 73.2ms | Allocations: 17729)
2019-11-19T00:55:04.216369240Z app[web.1]: web| I, [2019-11-19T00:55:04.199305 #14]  INFO -- : [9ac98910-3a38-496d-9f5e-f276bc590ba7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms (ActiveRecord: 5.8ms | Allocations: 19675)
2019-11-19T00:55:04.216376506Z app[web.1]: web| F, [2019-11-19T00:55:04.203841 #14] FATAL -- : [9ac98910-3a38-496d-9f5e-f276bc590ba7]
2019-11-19T00:55:04.216380926Z app[web.1]: web| [9ac98910-3a38-496d-9f5e-f276bc590ba7] ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Formtastic::I18n::SCOPES
2019-11-19T00:55:04.216385058Z app[web.1]: web| Did you mean?  Sprockets):
2019-11-19T00:55:04.216388027Z app[web.1]: web| [9ac98910-3a38-496d-9f5e-f276bc590ba7]     1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)
```

The entire log: https://pastebin.com/raw/buWSveBZ

Only one section for entities works - this is the show action. Only two actions for entities work - these are `show` and `destroy`. Everyone else catches the error that I showed above.

I absolutely don't understand what's the matter.

I successfully use the identical `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file in two other Rails 6 applications. Below I will show an example of one of the file for ActiveAdmin:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

ActiveAdmin.register User do
  menu priority: 5

  permit_params :email, :full_name, :roles, :password, :password_confirmation

  remove_filter :users_roles

  controller do
    def find_resource
      scoped_collection.find_by!(pkey: params[:id])
    end
  end

  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :pkey
    column :email
    column :full_name
    column :roles
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :email
      f.input :full_name
      f.input :roles
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

I'm hope for your help.

Comment: The basic error is that the ruby engine can't find the definition of `Formtastic::I18n::SCOPES`. Does `Formtastic::I18n::SCOPES` or `Formtastic::I18n` or simply `Formatstic` work in a rails console? Have you run `rails generate formtastic:install` (as per [their setup docs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#installation))?

Comment: The file where it's defined is [here](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/i18n.rb). Bottom line is you need to make sure that file exists in, or is copied to, a place that Rails includes or requires. This *might* happen in the install task, or maybe there's some additional `require`ing that needs to happen. You could probably hack it by copying the file somewhere you know, but I'd use that only as a last resort since that's obviously not how it's supposed to work :-)

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz I didn't touch formtastic at all. ActiveAdmin requires this. And in other projects I have never touched formtastic before. And in the installation of ActiveAdmin there is nothing about it. I did what you requested in the console. In response, I received an array, which is described in the source code that you provided. That is, everything seems normal.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz I have an idea about `ActiveSupport::Inflector`. Deployment will be completed now and I will say for sure.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz No, it didn’t help.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I have a rails 6 app that I hadn't touched in about a year and was getting a similar error despite never having an issue with my other rails app that I use regularly -- `uninitialized constant Formtastic::Util`

Commenter above's advice of running `rails generate formtastic:install` did the trick for me. Thanks!